# problem with getting each segment resulted through K means segmentation in seperate images using Python and Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, k-means, image-segmentation

I am using python and openCv for a brain segmentation project. I have segmented the brain MRI image using K means segmentation. I want to get each segment resulted through k means segmentation in seperate images. please help me in this.

```
#k_means segmentation
epsilon = 0.01
number_of_iterations = 50
number_of_clusters = 4
print(criteria, 'Criteria K_means parameters')
#plt.imshow(criteria)

#k means segmentation
_, labels, centers =cv2.kmeans(kmeans_input, number_of_clusters, None, 
                               flags)
print(labels.shape, 'k-means segmentation')
#plt.imshow(labels)

#Adopting the labels
labels = labels.flatten('F')
for x in range (number_of_clusters): labels[labels == x] = centers [x]
print(labels.shape, 'adopting the tables value')
#plt.imshow(labels)
```

Comment: Might be easier using kmeans from either sklearn or skimage. See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html and https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.slic. See example at bottom of https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.11-k-means.html for applying to an image.

Comment: See also https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_color_quantization.html

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using sklearn kmeans segmentation as follows. I show how to create the segmented image and then select one color to present. I create a mask from thresholding the one color and then apply the mask to blacken out the other colors in the segmented image. You can write a loop over each color to get them all. It is also possible to use the mask to make the non-color be transparent rather than black. But I do not show that here. Or you can just save the binary masks.

Input:

[image]

```
#!/bin/python3.7

from skimage import io
from sklearn import cluster
import sys
import cv2

# read input and convert to range 0-1
image = io.imread('barn.jpg')/255.0
h, w, c = image.shape

# reshape to 1D array
image_2d = image.reshape(h*w, c)

# set number of colors
numcolors = 6

# do kmeans processing
kmeans_cluster = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=int(numcolors))
kmeans_cluster.fit(image_2d)
cluster_centers = kmeans_cluster.cluster_centers_
cluster_labels = kmeans_cluster.labels_

# need to scale result back to range 0-255
newimage = cluster_centers[cluster_labels].reshape(h, w, c)*255.0
newimage = newimage.astype('uint8')
io.imshow(newimage)
io.show()

# select cluster 3 (in range 1 to numcolors) and create mask
lower = cluster_centers[3]*255
upper = cluster_centers[3]*255
lower = lower.astype('uint8')
upper = upper.astype('uint8')
mask = cv2.inRange(newimage, lower, upper)

# apply mask to get layer 3
layer3 = newimage.copy()
layer3[mask == 0] = [0,0,0]
io.imshow(layer3)
io.show()

# save kmeans clustered image and layer 3
io.imsave('barn_kmeans.gif', newimage)
io.imsave('barn_kmeans_layer3.gif', layer3)
```

Clustered Image:

[image]

Result for color 3:

[image]

ADDITION:

For a grayscale image, the following works for me.

```
#!/bin/python3.7

from skimage import io
from sklearn import cluster
import sys
import cv2

# read input and convert to range 0-1
image = io.imread('barn_gray.jpg',as_gray=True)/255.0
h, w = image.shape

# reshape to 1D array
image_2d = image.reshape(h*w,1)

# set number of colors
numcolors = 6

# do kmeans processing
kmeans_cluster = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=int(numcolors))
kmeans_cluster.fit(image_2d)
cluster_centers = kmeans_cluster.cluster_centers_
cluster_labels = kmeans_cluster.labels_

# need to scale result back to range 0-255
newimage = cluster_centers[cluster_labels].reshape(h, w)*255.0
newimage = newimage.astype('uint8')
io.imshow(newimage)
io.show()

# select cluster 3 (in range 1 to numcolors) and create mask
# note the cluster numbers and corresponding colors are not constant from run to run
lower = cluster_centers[3]*255
upper = cluster_centers[3]*255
lower = lower.astype('uint8')
upper = upper.astype('uint8')
print(lower)
print(upper)
mask = cv2.inRange(newimage, lower, upper)

# apply mask to get layer 3
layer3 = newimage.copy()
layer3[mask == 0] = [0]
io.imshow(layer3)
io.show()

# save kmeans clustered image and layer 3
io.imsave('barn_gray_kmeans.gif', newimage)
io.imsave('barn_gray_kmeans_layer3.gif', layer3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am going to try it now.

Comment: I tried the your advice but I am having some problem as I am trying to segment a grayscale image into a 4 colours. I think my problem is with 
# read input and convert to range 0-1
image = io.imread('barn.jpg')/255.0
h, w, c = image.shape

can you give me an advice on that?

Comment: See my ADDITION in my answer for a grayscale image.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help it worked for me as well. I just reshaped according to your addition. newimage = cluster_centers[cluster_labels].reshape(h, w)*255.0 Thank you again!!